# Detect when <img> src is updated

Tags: html, streaming, remote-desktop

I have tested a neat little project found on CodeProject: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371955/Motion-JPEG-Streaming-Server

Basically, when the project runs, it streams the desktop to any connected clients. The clients connect using their browser. The programs streams JPEG images of the desktop.

I noticed that all that is in the HTML -- client side -- is the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=0.1">
        <style type="text/css"></style>
    </head>
    <body style="margin: 0px;">
        <img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="http://54.194.225.174:8080/">
    </body>
</html>
```

What I would like to know, is when the `<img> src` gets updated. 
Is there a way I can measure the time between frame updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure this will work, but you could give it a try.  I don't have a working url for an image server like that.

HTML

```
<body style="margin: 0px;">
    <img id= "imageFrame" style="-webkit-user-select: none;width:400px;" src="http://localhost/image.png" >
    <div id="intervals"></div>
</body>
```

Javascript / jQuery

```
$(function() {
    var priorLoad = new Date().getTime();
    var count = 0;

    $('#imageFrame').on('load', function () {
        var thisLoad = new Date().getTime();
        var interval = thisLoad - priorLoad;
        $('#intervals').append($('<div/>').attr("id", "image" + count).addClass("someClass").append("<span/>").text(interval));
        priorLoad = thisLoad;
        count++;
    });
});
```

Comment: Not quite sure how your refresh the image or check to see if has changed.  Would be nice to have a working URL for the image server.   I"ll have to look at the project.

Comment: You can try this URL: http://54.194.225.174:8080/
I have the server running, for now.

Comment: Scrap that - your suggestion works! -- but in Firefox - not in Chrome for some reason!